# KIVY: Why wont the accordion properly load it with the title text visable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, kivy-language

For some reason when I run the code my accordion titles are black and the title text is not visible, when comparing it to example code where the accordion are a dark grey with white text. The rest of the accordion works fine when I click on it, it expands and closes. The only problem is the accordion titles not properly working.

[image]

*.py

```
#imported from kivy framework
from kivy.app import App
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta
from kivy.clock import Clock
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.uix.image import Image
import dictionaryData
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.base import runTouchApp
import os
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.accordion import Accordion, AccordionItem



class Main_Screen(Screen):
    pass


class Dictionary_Screen(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        layout = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')    # instantiate BoxLayout
        self.add_widget(layout)    # add BoxLayout to screen

        btn2 = Button(
            text='change screen',
            size_hint=(.5, .05),
        )
        btn2.bind(on_press=self.changer)
        layout.add_widget(btn2)    # add Button to BoxLayout

        title = ["Title 1", "Title 2", "Title 3", "Title 4", "Title 5"]

        accordion = Accordion(orientation='vertical')    # instantiate Accordion
        layout.add_widget(accordion)    # add Accordion to BoxLayout

        for x in range(2):
            item = AccordionItem(title="Cheese",background_normal= "LogoFF.png")
            item.add_widget(Label(text='Very big content\n' * 2))
            accordion.add_widget(item)    # add AccordionItem to Accordion
    def changer(self,*args):
        print("ww")

#class for all screens
class ScreenManagement(ScreenManager):
   pass

class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
       # declaring time from python, and making it refresh every second
        self.now = datetime.now()
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update_clock, 1)


    def update_clock(self, *args):
        self.now = self.now + timedelta(seconds=1)
        self.root.get_screen("Main_Screen").ids["CurrentTime"].text = self.now.strftime("%H:%M:%S")

MainApp().run()
```

*.kv

```
#:kivy 1.0
#:import hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
#styles that will apply to all intences for each tag
<MDRaisedButton>:
    font_size:18
<Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
#declaring screen managers and printing them in this order
ScreenManagement:
    Main_Screen:
        name: "Main_Screen"
    Dictionary_Screen:
        name: "Dictionary_Screen"
<Main_Screen>:
    FloatLayout:
        spacing: 10
        canvas.before:
            Color:
                rgba: hex('#eff3fa')
            Rectangle:
                size: self.size
                pos: self.pos
        #Navbar
        MDToolbar:
            id: fb
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'top':1.0}
            size_hint_y:None
            height: 50
            title: "Virtual Assistant"
            md_bg_color: hex('#132843')
            Label:
                id: CurrentTime
                font_size:18
                size_hint_x: .1
                color: (1,1,1,1)
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            spacing: 10
            padding: 50
            canvas.before:
                Color:
                    rgba: hex('#000')
                Rectangle:
                    size: self.size
                    pos: self.pos
            pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.5, 'center_y': 0.5}
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            Button:
                text: "Dictionary"
                on_release:
                    app.root.current = "Dictionary_Screen"
<Dictionary_Screen>:
    Label:
        id: box
        color: (1,0,1,1)
```

Is there a way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AccordionItemTitle` is a `Label`, and your `<Label>:` rule sets all text in all `Labels` to black. You can fix the problem by removing the lines:

```
<Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
```

from your `kv` file. It is generally a bad idea to make a `kv` rule for a commonly used `Widget`. A better approach would be to create a custom class like:

```
<BlackLabel@Label>:
    color: 0,0,0,1
```

and use `BlackLabel` where you want such a `Label`.

Comment: Once again you've saved me, thank you so much. This any documentation or guide on this because when reading the Kivy documentation, I feel it is quite bare on what it explains and I want to become better at using Kivy.

Comment: The [API](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.html) is good as a reference, but the [guides](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/gettingstarted/intro.html) are better for actually understanding the implications of the `API`. And particularly the [Kv language guide](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/guide/lang.html).